# negative numeric values and negative sign at the end . Need an expression to format the negative sign from the end to the front of the numeric values

Tags: sql, ssis

I have values which are numeric and negative and negative sign at the end . Need an expression to format the negative sign from the end to the front of the numeric values

for ex :

values :

```
22.50
-22.60
22.90-
23.46-
24.50-
```

i want the output as

```
22.50
-22.60
-22.90
-23.46
-24.50
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the value is a string, then:

```
select (case when val like '%-' then '-' + replace(val, '-', '')
             else val
        end)
```

If the value is stored as a number, then the application is adding the minus sign at the end.  You can convert to a string in the database, something like `cast(val as varchar(255))`.  The database should place the negative sign first.

Comment: I have the datatype as numeric(10,5) in the destination table  and i want to have derived column expression to check if the negative sign is coming at the end of the number for ex : 22.45- then to format the negative sign to the front of the number and insert it to desination table as -22.45

Comment: @sibanandapani . . . If the data type is numeric, then the application layer is placing the negative sign.  You can just cast the value to a string (in the database) to ensure that the value goes at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The following query assumes the following:

- you want to `insert into` a `table` called `DestinationTable`
- `DestinationTable` has a single `column` called `destinationColumn` for the sake of simplicity
- your values are stored in `SourceTable.sourceColumn`
- none of them are `null`s, empty strings or non numeric values

`insert into DestinationTable(destinationColumn)
select case when right(sourceColumn, 1) = '-' then concat('-', substring(sourceColumn, 1, length(sourceColumn) - 1))
                                              else sourceColumn
end
from SourceTable;`

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP needs a SSIS solution:

Use derived Column with a if then else ( test? true:false)

```
right(val,1) == "-" ? (DT_NUMERIC,10,5) ("-" + left(val,len(val)-1)) : (DT_NUMERIC,10,5) val
```

This assumes val is read originally as a string.